# Cannot grab the value of the user's input with jquery while using DateTimePicker plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey StackOverflow wizards! I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, but maybe you can help me.

I'm building a giant form wizard with lots of user input. The form has multiple tabs and on the first page I have an input where the user chooses a Start Date and an input where a user chooses an End Date. The last tab is a summary of all of the user's chosen inputs.

I'm trying to grab the value of the Start Date and End Date and spit them into a span element on the last tab of the form wizard. I'm using the DateTimePicker plugin [here](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker).

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
    <p><span id="confirmation-start-date"></span></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
    <p><span id="confirmation-end-date"></span></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
    <p><span id="confirmation-start-date"></span></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
    <p><span id="confirmation-end-date"></span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my JQuery:

```
var projectStartDate = $('#project-start-date').blur(function() {
  $('#project-start-date').data('DateTimePicker').date();
  console.log(projectStartDate);
});
$('#confirmation-start-date').text(projectStartDate);

//get the value of End Date and spit it onto the summary page
var projectEndDate = $('#project-end-date').blur(function() {
  $('#project-end-date').data('DateTimePicker').date();
  console.log(projectEndDate);
});
$('#confirmation-end-date').text(projectStartDate);
```

With this current code text stating [Object object] gets returned in the 's for those inputs.

Console.log also returns an object, rather than a value.

I'm super new to jquery/javascript and any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**My Full Javascript Code:**

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  //Escrow Form Validations
  $().ready(function() {
    $(".no input").radio('check');

    var $validator = $("#wizardForm").validate({
      rules: {
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true,
          minlength: 5
        },
        first_name: {
          required: false,
          minlength: 5
        },
        last_name: {
          required: false,
          minlength: 5
        },
        price: {
          number: true
        }
      }
    });

    //Tab Control for Form Wizard
    $('#wizardCard').bootstrapWizard({
      tabClass: 'nav nav-pills nav-pills-blue',
      nextSelector: '.btn-next',
      previousSelector: '.btn-back',
      onNext: function(tab, navigation, index) {
        var $valid = $('#wizardForm').valid();

        if (!$valid) {
          $validator.focusInvalid();
          return false;
        }
      },
      onInit: function(tab, navigation, index) {

        //check number of tabs and fill the entire row
        var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
        $width = 100 / $total;

        $display_width = $(document).width();

        if ($display_width < 600 && $total > 3) {
          $width = 50;
        }

        navigation.find('li').css('width', $width + '%');
      },
      onTabClick: function(tab, navigation, index) {
        // Disable the posibility to click on tabs
        return false;
      },
      onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
        var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
        var $current = index + 1;

        var wizard = navigation.closest('.card-wizard');

        // If it's the last tab then hide the last button and show the finish instead
        if ($current >= $total) {
          $(wizard).find('.btn-next').hide();
          $(wizard).find('.btn-finish').show();
        } else if ($current == 1) {
          $(wizard).find('.btn-back').hide();
        } else {
          $(wizard).find('.btn-back').show();
          $(wizard).find('.btn-next').show();
          $(wizard).find('.btn-finish').hide();
        }
      }
    });
  });

$().ready(function() {
  //Max amount of milestones
  var max_milestone = 5

  // Initial Milestone Count
  var x = 1;

  //function for add milestone button
  //if button.add-milestone is clicked
  $('.add-milestone').click(function(e) {
    //console.log('dope')
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_milestone) { // if the milestone count is smaller than 5
      x++; //increment milestones
      $('.additional-milestones').before('<div class="milestone"><h4>Milestone #1</h4><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">Milestone Title</label><input class="form-control" type="text" name="Milestone[' + (x - 1) + '][MilestoneTitle]" placeholder="Dusty Bench" required /></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">Deadline</label><input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" name="Milestone[' + (x - 1) + '][MilestoneTitle]" placeholder="Deadline" required/></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">Milestone Description</label><textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" name="Milestone[' + (x - 1) + '][MilestoneTitle]" rows="3" required> </textarea></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><a class="delete-milestone btn btn-danger"> - Delete This Milestone</a></div></div><hr></div>');
      $('.delete-milestone').click(function() {
        //console.log('dope')
        $(this).parents(".milestone").remove();
      });
    }
  });
  //then
  //populate with milestone form with Milestone+Next Milestone Number

  //Delete Milestone 
});

//Buying extra TB of Storage
//If 'yes' radio dial is chosen
//show TB input and submit
$('.yes input').on('toggle', function() {
  $(".buy-more-storage").show('slow');
  $(".no input").radio('uncheck');
});

$('.no input').on('toggle', function() {
  $(".buy-more-storage").hide('slow');
  $(".yes input").radio('uncheck');
});

///Date-Time Picker Classes
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  icons: {
    time: "fa fa-clock-o",
    date: "fa fa-calendar",
    up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
    down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
    previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
    next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
    today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
    clear: 'fa fa-trash',
    close: 'fa fa-remove'
  },
  format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
});

//Function for flaring error if picked date is before current date
//if(pickedDate <=todaysDate){
//return true;
//}
//else{
//return false;
//}

//If 'Buyer' is chosen from the Role dropdown menu then the buyer's choices are shown
$('#project-role').on('change.states', function() {
  $(".buyer-choices").toggle($(this).val() == 'Payer');
}).trigger('change.buyer-choices');

//If 'Asset-Producer' is chosen from the Role dropdown menu then the Asset Producer's choices are shown
$('#project-role').on('change.states', function() {
  $(".asset-producer-choices").toggle($(this).val() == 'Payee');
}).trigger('change.asset-producer-choices');

//If 'Credit-Card' is chosen from the Payment Options
$('#payment-type').on('change.states', function() {
  $(".credit-card-form").toggle($(this).val() == 'credit-card');
}).trigger('change.credit-card-form');

//If 'Link Bank Account' is chosen from the Payment Options
$('#payment-type').on('change.states', function() {
  $(".link-bank-account").toggle($(this).val() == 'bank-transfer');
}).trigger('change.link-bank-account');

//If 'Credit-Card' is chosen from the Project Setup Fee
$('#projectFeePayment').on('change.states', function() {
  $(".projectFeePaymentCCForm").toggle($(this).val() == 'projectFeePaymentCC');
}).trigger('change.projectFeePaymentCCForm');

//If 'Link Bank Account' is chosen from the Project Setup Fee
$('#projectFeePayment').on('change.states', function() {
  $(".projectFeePaymentBAForm").toggle($(this).val() == 'projectFeePaymentBT');
}).trigger('change.projectFeePaymentBAForm');

//Send Escrow Project button at end of wizard
function onFinishWizard() {
  //Affirmation of project being
  $('#wizardForm').submit(function(e) {
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = "<?php echo $portalfqdn; ?>" + $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
      url: formURL,
      type: "POST",
      data: postData,
      success: function(data) {
        //var emailResult = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        if (data.Message.Code === "00") {
          swal({
            title: "Success!",
            text: "Your new escrow project has been sent for approval! Look out for an alert indicating when your project has been approved!",
            type: "success",
            confirmButtonText: "Ok",
          });
        } else {
          swal({
            title: "Error!",
            text: "There was a problem with your form submission.",
            type: "error",
            confirmButtonText: "Fix Errors",
          });
        }
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#email-search-result').removeClass("success");
        $('#email-search-result').addClass("error");
        $('#email-search-result').html("An error occurred.");
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
  });

  $('#wizardForm').submit(); //Submit  the FORM

  //If there are errors flag this message, change button to go back to form to address these errors 
  //$('.sweet-confirm.btn.btn-info.btn-fill').click(function(){
  //replace this with ajax submit
  //window.location.href='updated-escrow-list.html';
  //$('#wizardForm').submit(); //Submit  the FORM
};


//get the value of project name and spit it onto the summary page
$('.ProjectName').keyup(function() {
  $('#confirmation-project-name').text($(this).val());
});

//Begin get start and end dates of project and spit them onto summary tab
$().ready(function() {
  var projectStartDate;
  var projectEndDate;

  $('#project-start-date').blur(function() {
    projectStartDate = $(this).val();
  });

  $('#project-end-date').blur(function() {
    projectEndDate = $(this).val();
  });

  console.log(projectStartDate);
  console.log(projectEndDate);

  $('#confirmation-start-date').html(projectStartDate);
  $('#confirmation-end-date').html(projectEndDate);
});
//End----------------------------------------------------//

//get the value of project collaborator and spit it onto the summary page
$('.collaborator').keyup(function() {
  $('#confirmation-collaborator').text($(this).val());
});

//get the value of project deliverable description and spit it onto the summary page
$('.ProjectDeliverable').keyup(function() {
  $('#confirmation-project-deliverable').text($(this).val());
});

//get the value of project role and spit it onto the summary page
$('.ProjectRole').change(function() {
  var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
  $('#confirmation-project-role').text(selectedText);
});

//if .ProjectRole is Buyer then show chosen payment method

//if .ProjectRole is asset-producer then show chosen payment recieving method

//get the value of project amount and spit it onto the summary page
$('.ProjectAmount').keyup(function() {
  $('#confirmation-project-amount').text($(this).val());
  console.log($('#confirmation-project-amount').text());
});

var projectAmount = parseInt($('#confirmation-project-amount').text());
console.log(projectAmount);

//search for a user by email address to see if they have a Stratuscore account
$('#email-search').click(function(e) {
  if ($('#ProjectPartner').val() === '') {
    return false;
  }
  var postData = {
    Email: $('#ProjectPartner').val(),
    ApiAction: "find-user-by-email"
  }

  var formURL = "<?php echo $portalfqdn; ?>account-api.php";
  $.ajax({
    url: formURL,
    type: "POST",
    data: postData,
    success: function(data) {
      //var emailResult = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      if (data.Message.Code === "00") {
        $('#email-search-result').removeClass("error alert alert-danger");
        $('#email-search-result').addClass("success alert alert-success");
      } else {
        $('#email-search-result').removeClass("success");
        $('#email-search-result').addClass("error alert alert-danger");
      }
      $('#email-search-result').html(data.Message.Description);
      $('#email-search-result').show();
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $('#email-search-result').removeClass("success");
      $('#email-search-result').addClass("error");
      $('#email-search-result').html("The user you are searching for wasn't found. Please check the email entered and try again.");
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
}); < /script>
```

**SOLUTION**

After much frustration at myself for being a javascript novice, I realized I had a scope issue on my hands and instead wrote functions to handle the DOM updating and passed the variables as parameters to those functions. Works for now!

```
//Begin get start and end dates of project and spit them onto summary tab
function updateStartDate (projectStartDate) {
    $('#confirmation-start-date').html(projectStartDate);
    console.log(projectStartDate);
}

function updateEndDate (projectEndDate) {
    $('#confirmation-end-date').html(projectEndDate);
    console.log(projectEndDate);
}

$('#project-start-date').blur(function() {
    var projectStartDate = $(this).val();
        //console.log(projectStartDate);
    updateStartDate(projectStartDate);
});

$('#project-end-date').blur(function() {
    var projectEndDate = $(this).val();
        //console.log(projectEndDate);
    updateEndDate(projectEndDate);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the great things about jQuery is that almost all its methods return the element on which they're called, thus allowing you to chain a bunch of them together. However, because the methods almost always return an *element*, something like this...

```
var projectStartDate = $('#project-start-date').blur( ... );
```

... is just going to set `projectStartDate = $('#project-start-date');`, rather than its value. I've created a brief example to demonstrate this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/ajn1z165/1/).

---

If you want to set `projectStartDate` equal to the *value* of this field, consider something like the following...

```
var projectStartDate;
var projectEndDate;

$('#project-start-date').blur(function() {
    projectStartDate = $(this).val();
});

$('#project-end-date').blur(function() {
    projectEndDate = $(this).val();
});

$('#confirmation-start-date').html(projectStartDate);
$('#confirmation-end-date').html(projectEndDate);
```

Comment: Thank you SO much for the help! The correct value is showing up when I console.log the variable, BUT for some sad reason I'm not getting any output to the span. It's just empty.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't even notice. Yes, you'll need `.html()`. `text()` takes no arguments and cannot be used to *set* an element's text - it is readonly.

Comment: Crazy, I'm still getting empty spans!

Comment: If you do `console.log(projectStartDate)` immediately before `$('#confirmation-start-date').html(projectStartDate)`, does it output the correct value?

Comment: I did console.log's within those functions and I'm getting the correct return values, but they are not populating within the <span>'s.

Comment: I meant what if you take the console.log *out* of the function, and put it just before you populate the spans?

Comment: Ah I get an undefined. Do these need to go within the function?

Comment: What that tells me is that something is fishy. Can you post your entire JavaScript code? These aren't two different pages are they?

Comment: Updated to add full javascript code. My apologies, it's not very DRY. Someday I'll be good at this :''(.

Comment: Fixed this myself! Scope was all crazy!